# communication between multiple jvms

Tags: java

I guys,
i have some problem with communication between multiple jvms in java.
then I expose my scenario.
I have 1 jvm, servers, and other jvm, client. The client, when active, must connect to the server and when the server sends an information to all clients that are connected.
This occurs asynchronously.

I thought of using the jms. Could you tell me if it is a good choice or is it better to use the classic socket?

Also using the jms as I say to send the message to all consumers in one queue?

thanks and sorry for my bad english

exemple:
`
this is an exemple:

```
public class JmsMessageListenerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI(
                "broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
        broker.start();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Producer
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
            String payload = "Important Task";
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
            producer.send(msg);

            // Consumer
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer"));
            connection.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            session.close();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            broker.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which protocol are you going to use?

Comment: WebSocket will fit your requirements. JMS is ok but more complicated.

Comment: I think to useTCP.

Comment: If you are going to build your own Server. It will be wrong decision. It is doable but It will be very hard work.

Comment: @Loc use socke? give meany suggestions

Comment: @Gear It seems that you are trying to build a chat or something similar. WebSockets is the most reasonable choice then

Comment: It is not a chat, the client never send messages to server. Only server when an event occurs send a messagge. Finally the JVMS are in the same physical machine

Comment: @Gear: I mean WebSocket technology. Not Java net Socket api (low api level). Your requirements requires Server push feature. WebSocket fits perpect. You can use JavaEE 7 as a WebSocket server and use any Java WebSocket client.

Comment: though my application it not is a web app?